# sending POST Request similar to "curl -d" from AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, curl, get

I need to send a `POST` request similar `curl -d` command from my AngularJS app.

```
curl http://localhost:80; --data "JSONOBJ"
```

Here is the `service`:

```
Services.factory('Set', ['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return $resource('http://localhost:80/?value=:JSONOBJ', {}, {
      query: {method:'POST'}
    });
  }]);
```

and `controller` code:

```
 $scope.pass = function(data) {
  var newData = [];
  newData.push({
      data: [{
          "id": data,
          "type": "record"]}
  });

  Set.query({
      value: newData
  }).$promise.then(function(data) {
    //
  });
};
```

But I get `404` from the server after sending the request. I think I am not properly passing the data (-d in curl). Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: If you are sending data throw the call, seems like a POST call instead of a GET. --data is to specify the post data content.

Comment: sorry. my mistake. I've updated the the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you should us is post() instead of query(). The save() function issues a POST request. You are overriding the query() method which is used for GET calls not POST.

Your controller should looks like this:

```
Set.save({
      ego: ego},{
      data: JSON.stringify(editItems)
  }).$promise.then(function(result) {

  });
```

Please note that I added two parameters to the save call

1. First object refers to the parameters.
2. Second parameter will refer to the data that you want to Post.

non-GET actions for the $Resource service : Resource.([parameters], postData, [success], [error])

Your service:

```
AppServices.factory('Set', ['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return $resource('http://localhost:7776/');
  }]);
```

**NOTE:**
For a POST request, you may still have a query string parameters, but this is uncommon and does not have anything to do with the data that you are POSTing.